# Stuck on getting mongoose, node and express to play nice together

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am following along with a node.js and express tutorial at **[DailyJS](http://dailyjs.com/2010/11/08/node-tutorial-2/)** and have already hit a wall.

In the tutorial it says to do this:

```
 mongoose = require('mongoose').Mongoose
 db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/nodepad')
```

but beforehand he was talking about the code inside the `app.js` file, so I assume he means for the above code to go inside `app.js` but I don't know. At this point I download the nodepad from github to see where he actually put the mongoose code, and I can't find the above code anywhere in the entire application!

So I am at a loss. Things are already confusing because a default skeleton site made by express is different in many ways to the tutorial, because express has changed a lot in the 2 years since the tutorial was written.

So i'm trying to follow along but I just get really stuck where he says write some code but gives no indication where this code is meant to go.

And afterwards the tutorial says to add a `models.js` file, and I wonder where this goes, inside the directory perhaps?

(I also understand the above code is outdated and the correct code can be found **[here](http://mongoosejs.com/)**, the problem is not the code but where in express its meant to be placed)

Please give me some guidance.

Thanks

Comment: Both of those go in app.js.  I can give you some more details.  I use mongoose and express all the time.  I don't use `var mongoose = require('mongoose').Mongoose` All I use is `var mongoose = require('mongoose')`

Comment: Thanks so much, i'm just giving this a go now. Do you mind if contact you if I need some more help? Or would you prefer I post more questions to stackoverflow.com? Also do you want to paste that comment into the answer box and I will check it as correct. Cheers!

Comment: Not a problem. I will make this an answer. I will be happy to help any way I can.

Comment: Did that work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of those go in `app.js`. I can give you some more details. I use mongoose and express all the time. I don't use `var mongoose = require('mongoose').Mongoose` All I use is `var mongoose = require('mongoose')`

Let me know if you need any further help.